# how do you align javascript : assignments in textmate

Tags: textmate

how do you align javascript : assignments in textmate?

I see that = assignments are aligned with the keyboard shortcut, but couldn't find a way to align : assignments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a bundle aptly named [Align.](https://github.com/sicher/align-tmbundle)

The semicolon is not really an assignment operator: it's beter to see it as a separator between a key ans its value.